# Problema con el header location PHP

Tags: php

tengo un registro y login de usuarios, el problema es que cuando hago el login y el logout me tira el siguiente error y tengo que darle dos clicks a cerrar sesion para que lo haga:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at

El codigo es asi:

```php
    public function login(){
            if (isset($_POST)) {

                $usuario = new Usuario();
                $usuario->setEmail($_POST['email']);
                $usuario->setPassword($_POST['password']);

                $identity = $usuario->login();

                if ($identity && is_object($identity)) {
                    $_SESSION['identity'] = $identity;

                    if ($identity->rol == 'admin') {
                        $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
                    }

                }else{
                    $_SESSION['error_login'] = "Identificacion fallida";
                }
            }
            header("Location:".base_url);
        }

        public function logout(){
            if (isset($_SESSION['identity'])) {
                unset($_SESSION['identity']);
            }

            if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {  
                unset($_SESSION['admin']);
            }
            header("Location:".base_url);
        }
```

El login lo uso desde el formulario y el logout desde un link de Cerrar Sesion en una vista que es registro.php :

```
<form action="<?=base_url?>usuario/login" method="POST" id="login">

    <div class="input_field">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="input">
        <i class="far fa-user"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="input_field">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" class="input">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="input_field">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Muestra y/o explica el contexto. ¿Desde donde llamas a `login` o a `logout`?

Comment: Revisa el archivo donde tienes las funciones login y logout, probablemente hay alguna llamada a **header** anterior.

Comment: ¿Qué es *base_url*? ¿una variable? ¿una función? ¿dónde se define?

Comment: El el archivo donde tengo las funciones es el controlador de usuarios (UsuarioController) y ahi tengo la funcion save, login y logout... En las 3 funciones utilizo el header location una vez que realizan su trabajo, es una buena practica repetirlo en cada funcion???
base_url es la url index que defini con la funcion define

Comment: Primero deberías ver el error real que te ocurre, por ejemplo, mirando el error.log del servidor ya que ahí, se especificará el warning o error que recibe la página. Yo sospecho que será un warning y es suficiente para romper el header ya que cualquier cosa escrita antes del header lo rompe. En caso de ser un warning, por ejemplo, que base_url no está definido, simplemente lo defines, pero eso dependerá del warning/error que recibas.

Answer (score 2):

eso suele pasar porque "escribes" algo antes de modificar la las cabeceras de PHP.

Me explico mejor, cuando modificas la variable global $_SESSION, se modifican las cabeceras que PHP envía al cliente, ya que al final la variable $_SESSION es una cookie que se envía al cliente en la cabecera del mensaje HTTP.

El problema es que estas cabeceras se generan automáticamente cuando hacer el primer echo o el primer var_dump, en definitiva, la primera vez que haces una salida de texto hacia el cliente.

Si después intentas modificarlas, te dice que no se puede modificar porque se "han sido enviadas".

Para solucionarlo, haz las modificaciones que necesites en la variable $_SESSION antes de hacer ningún echo.

La buena noticia es que PHP también te indica dónde se realiza esa salida de texto.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at **/some/file.php:X**) in **/some/file.php on line Y**

Normalmente este es el error que da. Pues en la línea **X** tienes dónde se envía esa información antes de modificar la variable $_SESSION  en la línea **Y**.

Envía esa información después para solucionar el warning.

Un saludo.

## Edito

No he tenido en cuenta el código que va entre el código PHP, es decir, el código que va entre la apertura y cierre de las etiquetas `<?PHP>`. Esto también se considera una salida y por tanto después de alguna salida de este tipo, tampoco se podrá modificar la cabecera de HTTP.

## Fuentes:

[How to fix “Headers already sent” error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me estuve fijando y sigo sin poder solucionarlo, en la linea X tengo una etiqueta a con el logo de la pagina y la verdad eso no me dice nada ya que es puro html.

Comment: Pero ¿ese código html lo estás imprimiendo directamente en pantalla? ¿O lo almacenas en una variable que después imprimes? Y sé que es una tontería, pero mira que en qué archivo te indica el error, a ver si no estás mirando otro. Ya me dices, un saludo.

Comment: Si, directamente es html que sale directamente en pantalla.

Comment: Pues ese es el problema, no puedes hacer eso, después de enviar algo al usuario ya no puedes modificar la variable $_SESSION.

Comment: Sigo sin poder solucionarlo, ahi use la funcion headers_sent en mi funcion de logout y evidentemente me indica que cuando hago el logout las cabeceras ya se han enviado... el tema es que no se que es lo que se esta mandando antes y como solucionarlo! Me estoy volviendo loco

Comment: Hola, alguien me ayudo a resolverlo usando lo siguiente:

En el index.php coloca hasta arriba

ob_start();

y abajo de tu header("location:ruta");

header("location:ruta");

ob_end_flush();

Pero no me explica que es lo que hacen esas lineas